# my boolean is turning true before i want it to be

Tags: boolean

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc9jv.png)

I have 2 moving squares(drawn from left top corner) that should turn color when they overlap. I made this boolean function to check if they overlap.

But when I run my code the boolean doesn't seem to be entirely correct because they change color before they overlap.

```
boolean overlap(float posx1, float posx2, float posy1, float posy2)
{   
  if (posx1 > pos x 2 + size || posx1 + size < posx2 || posy1 > posy2 + size || posy1 + size < posy2)
  {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

The boolean works for the y-positions but not the x.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow - could you please specify what language/framework you are using and include the code you used to call this method. You also appear to have a typo `pos x 2` - is that meant to be `posx2`?

Comment: maybe `(posx1 >= posx2 && posx1 <= posx2+size) && (posy1 >= posy2 && posy1 <= posy2+size)` seems more appropriate? You put all the conditions in or and for sure it won't work in any circumstance